# Unable to create “Union[bool, int]” type

Tags: python, types, python-3.6

## Problem

PEP-484 section [Union types](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#union-types) states:

> A type factored by Union[T1, T2, ...] is a supertype of all types T1, T2, etc., so that a value that is a member of one of these types is acceptable for an argument annotated by Union[T1, T2, ...].

And since boolean type `bool` is a subtype of the integer type `int` in Python it seems impossible to have `Union[bool, int]` because it will be flattened to `int`.

That does not seem right, as boolean and integer semantically different types despite the fact that boolean is a sub-class of the integer.

And after reading PEP-483 section [Types vs. Classes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/#id9) that states:

> Every class is a type as discussed above. But it is tricky and error prone to implement a class that exactly represents semantics of a given type, and it is not a goal of PEP 484. The static types described in PEP 484, should not be confused with the runtime classes.

I believe that this is one of these error-prone cases. This issue arose from a real use-case where I was using type-alias for validations and got a problem in this example:

```
>>> from typing import Union
>>>
>>> ValidTypes = Union[bool, int, str]
>>> example = [True, 42, 'spam']
>>>
>>> all(it.__class__ in ValidTypes.__args__ for it in example)
>>> False
```

What might be an appropriate solution to this problem, considering that I am stuck with Python 3.6.9 for a while?

Comment: ```3.7.6``` - ```all(it.__class__ in ValidTypes.__args__ for it in example)``` returns ```True```

Comment: Thanks, @JoshuaNixon but seems like I cannot upgrade from version 3.6.9 very soon.

Comment: I know this is ```mypy``` but  the issue was reported a few years ago here https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1850

Comment: Looks like this was fixed [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/f65e31fee3b55dfb6ed5398179d5c5d6b502dee5#diff-015978a768b517a38abbc0ecdea87f5a). If upgrading is not an option, you might need to provide some background for why you need to distinguish between `bool` and `int` here.

Comment: It's probably got something to do with the fact that `bool` is a subclass of `int` in Python.

Comment: Exactly, @martineau. Seems like it is only problem with Python 3.6.9.

Comment: Thanks, @chepner but I am afraid my specifics for such distinction would be too wordy and quite off-topic to the question.